# get data before sharing on facebook + popups

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'd like my users to share some content generated on the server, but would like NOT to generate that content before user clicks the Share button.

There are three routes to take:

1. a social button - I need some kind of event before the popup opens since the data is still not there. Is there such an event?
2. add button/link that fetches the data and then calls FB.ui({ method: 'share' ... }) - when FB.ui() is called, the browser asks the user to allow popups from the website because it's no longer user-triggered. Is there a way to use the fact that the user clicked the button in the first place?
3. make the user click a button to submit the info I need, get the results and only then display the Share button with the data from server - seems the default way to go but hits usability by making the user press 2 buttons (and wait in between)

I DON'T want the user to give the app any permissions (and then share directly via the api), it's too much for what the app is doing.

So the question is:
Is there a way to implement the functionality using route 1 or 2, or is there a better way, or is 3 the only route to go?

Comment: You can visit this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.1

Comment: Can't you just create the content on the first url-call? The Facebook scraper will load the page behind the url. I don't know if the scraper is only checking the page if someone shared the link already, or if it is checking the page as soon as the sdk parses the xfbml-share-button.

Comment: @LivingSoftware, I generate the content as soon as I can, but not before the user decides he wants to share it as the backend process is somewhat too consuming to do otherwise. So there's no url to scrap earlier than that.